# AutoMapper with static factory methods

Tags: c#, automapper

What is the best approach for using AutoMapper with value objects with static factory methods:

```
public class ImmutableDetail 
{
  public static ImmutableDetail Create(string detail) => new ImmutableDetail(detail);

      private ImmutableDetail(string detail)
      {
         Detail = detail;
      }

      public string Detail { get;}

    }
```

Where I want to be able to:

```
var immutableDetails = Mapper.Map<ImmutableDetail>(source);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With below classes:

```
public class DummySource
{
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}

public class ImmutableDetail
{
    public static ImmutableDetail Create(string detail) { return new ImmutableDetail(detail); }

    private ImmutableDetail(string detail)
    {
        Detail = detail;
    }

    public string Detail { get; private set; }
}
```

you can make a mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DummySource, ImmutableDetail>().ConstructUsing((DummySource ds) => ImmutableDetail.Create(ds.Detail));
var source = new DummySource { Detail = "Hello" };
var immutableDetails = Mapper.Map<ImmutableDetail>(source);
```